# How to add source code into wordpress post really?

Tags: shortcode, code

Ok, I have read and followed the instructions as written in this link:
http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

I have tried all other the solutions, including reinstall the whole wordpress site, installing syntax highlighting plugins etc. but it just din't work ?! Below is my published post in Twenty Thirteen. My post still display the code block as plain text as you can see.

[image: My post still display as plain text]

Edit:
I'm using self-hosted WP and installed (and activated) SyntaxHighlighter Evolved

It worked with single line code, but below is what it showed when I typed multiple lines of code:

[image]

Comment: The shortcode works on .com blogs only, it is provided by a plugin.

Comment: yes, yes, I mean I'm using my self-hosted WP blog and I also installed SyntaxHighlighter Evolved

Answer (score 2):

Since you are self hosting the blog, you will need to:

1. Install the [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/).
2. Make sure that you enable the plugin on your blog (this is not done automatically after install).

You should now be able to add the code to a post or page via either the visual or text editor.

```
[code language="css"]
your code here
[/code]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just din't work with multiple lines, ie: [code language="css"]
your code here 1
your code here 2
your code here 3
[/code]

Comment: Check that WordPress hasn't inserted a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) before the closing code tag. If so, try removing it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that sometimes but now I switch to another plugin and it works!